# Understanding alpha-beta pruning for simplified NIM

Tags: game-ai, minimax

This is a simple version of NIM: Two players alternately remove one, two or three coins from a stack initially containing 5 coins. The player who picks up the last coin loses.

What does alpha-beta pruning look like on the game tree for this game?

Comment: Welcome to AI.se! This is a place where we ask and answer questions about AI. Your post looks like a homework problem. Is there a *specific* part of it you're confused about that we can help you with? Right now, your post is too broad.

Comment: @PhilipRaeisghasem I prefer using the standard of the utility of a given question, regardless of it being homework or not.  Let me know if you think the recent edit has rendered it more suitable.

Comment: Oh, yes, the recent edit has none of the problems the original question had. The original format of "Find X. Find Y. Show Z" is what I was mostly objecting to as being too broad. It was also, technically, not a question.